# Expand package to package.json with tab completion even with package-lock.json

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion

I was once a very happy little node.js developer. I didn't realize how often I would run `vim package.json` on a daily basis, but apparently it was a lot. I'll get to that later.

Typically when I want to edit `package.json` I'll type out `vim pack`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> or perhaps `vim pac`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is muscle memory at this point.

Since npm@5, the `package-lock.json` file has introduced. This means that

`vim pac`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

opens the file `package`. This results in a lot of extra keystrokes and the workflow has changed to

`vim pac`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>`:qvim package.`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The result is a lot of wasted keystrokes, time, frustration, tears, and contemplation of a career in something other than software.

Is there any way to have completion for vim or in the shell in general expand `pac` or `pack` to `package.json` if the file is already there even if `package-lock.json` is also there? This could be completion for vim or just the shell in general. Presumably I'll never need to edit or inspect `package-lock.json`, so that file can be ignored for any completion as well. I also still want to make sure that compltion doesn't expand `package.json` if it's *not* there. I also don't want this to affect any other files, e.g. it shouldn't expand `circ`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `circle.yml` if both `circle.yml` and `circle-bak.yml` are both there... I'm only interested in `package.json`.

I tried `alias vimp="vim package.json"`, but I'm not satisfied with this since <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> is awkward to type since they use the same finger. I just want the completion to work like I'm used to.

Comment: `vim pac . tab Enter` should work fine.

Comment: @hek2mgl that is a little bit better but still not quite what I want. I want to be able to just `vim pac tab Enter`

Comment: Set your alias to `vimpa(ck?)?`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's the question if you really want that :). You can change the bash completion file, but that would be system wide. Or alternatively source a custom bash completion each time you start to work on the project. If that is ok I can show you how. Alternatively you can create a symlink to package.json, call it `foo` and use `vim foo`.

Comment: PS: just saw the suggestion to create an alias. That's probably the best and simplest solution.

Comment: @hek2mgl changing completion system wide would be what I want since this would apply to any package.json system-wide

Comment: @ExplosionPills Right, plus any `packaging-help.txt`, `pacman.bin` etc..

Comment: Imo `alias vimpac='vim package.json'` would be easy to use

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom rule for `vim` like this:

```
_vim() {
  local cur
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  if [[ $cur = pac* && -f package.json ]]; then
    COMPREPLY=( package.json )
    return 0
  fi
}

complete -F _vim vim
```

If you've typed anything more than `pac` before hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> and `package.json` exists, then this will auto-complete to `package.json`. The behaviour is only enabled for arguments to `vim`.